# Добавление новостей на двух страницах

Tags: dle

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтоб на двух страницах dle сайта были разные новости?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть просто стоит создать две разные категории и добавлять в них новости?